# POST form inside an asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net, forms, webforms, asp.net-3.5, http-post

A client of mine has asked for a 3rd party form to be integrated into their ASP.NET website. I've been instructed to simply copy the 3rd party code into the site where needed. However, the code is a form such as:

```
<form type="POST" action="http://domain.com/post.pl">
  <input />
  <input />
  .....
</form>
```

As the site is an ASP.NET website the body tag looks like this:

```
<body>
   <form runat="server">
   ...All code here...
   </form>
</body>
```

Therefore I cannot put this code in the page as I can't have a form tag inside the ASP.NET form tag, as the following is **invalid**:

```
<body>
    <form runat="server>
        ...Code here...
        <form type="POST" action="http://domain.com/post.pl">
            <input />
            <input />
            .....
        </form>
        ...Code here...
     </form>
</body>
```

How can I get just the fields in the 3rd party form to be posted to the 3rd Party URL?

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong to me, Your values will be posted to Action URL.

Comment: I can't put a form tag inside a form tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw the third-party form into a separate page and embed it in your page within an iframe.

Comment: Hi @Kon, thanks for your reply. I believe the form will then redirect the page to a search results page on their server. I believe if I did this in an iframe only the iframe would be redirected. I need the whole page to be redirected. Is there no way with ASP.NET that I can build a HTTP POST request or something? Thanks again

Comment: You can call a javascript function on the host page from the iframe, to redirect user.  Also, check this out:  http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent78.aspx